# Vue SSR: resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a hard time while I'm trying to resolve global components in the render function of a component in my SSR Vue app.

I get the error message "**[Vue warn]: resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup().**" when I call resolveComponent in the render function (in result the function just returns the input string). But the call in the setup function works as expected.

This is a minimal example of what I've tried. The real code is much more complex and of course the global components are not known in Main.vue.

The target platform does not support dynamic imports, so it's not an alternative.

Don't sure if I make it wrong or the warn message is misleading.

##### entryServer.ts

```
import { createSSRApp } from "vue";
import { renderToString } from 'vue/server-renderer'
import Example from '@/components/Example.vue'
import Main from '@/components/Main.vue'

const app = createSSRApp(Main)
app.component("Example", Example)

;(async function() {
  const appHtml = await renderToString(app)

  setResult(appHtml) // Platform specific
})()
```

##### Main.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, resolveComponent, h } from "vue";
import type {VNode} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Main",

  setup() {
    return {
      component: resolveComponent("Example")
    }
  },

  render(): VNode {
    console.log('setup', this.component)
    console.log('render', resolveComponent("Example"))

    return h(this.component)
  }
})
</script>
```

##### Example.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import {createTextVNode, defineComponent} from "vue"
import type {VNode} from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Example',

  render(): VNode {
    return createTextVNode("xxx")
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so sure not to have two instances of vue. But I have.

The target platform is an isolated-vm environment. After a lot of debugging I found out, that there is an error on how I resolve module imports. A second import is not delivering the same module instance.
That results in the described error.